# complex MySQL Order by not working

Tags: sql, mysql

Here is the select statement I'm using. The problem happens with the sorting. When it is like below, it only sorts by `t2.userdb_user_first_name`, doesn't matter if I put that first or second. When I remove that, it sorts just fine by the displayorder field value pair. So I know that part is working, but somehow the combination of the two causes the `first_name` to override it. What I want is for the records to be sorted by displayorder first, and then `first_name` within that.

```
SELECT t1.userdb_id
FROM default_en_userdbelements as t1
  INNER JOIN default_en_userdb AS t2 ON t1.userdb_id = t2.userdb_id
WHERE t1.userdbelements_field_name = 'newproject'
  AND t1.userdbelements_field_value = 'no'
  AND t2.userdb_user_first_name!='Default'
ORDER BY
  (t1.userdbelements_field_name = 'displayorder' AND t1.userdbelements_field_value),
  t2.userdb_user_first_name;
```

Edit: here is what I want to accomplish. I want to list the users (that are not new projects) from the userdb table, along with the details about the users that is stored in userdbelements. And I want that to be sorted first by `userdbelements.displayorder`, then by `userdb.first_name`. I hope that makes sense? Thanks for the really quick help!

Edit: Sorry for disappearing, here is some sample data

userdbelements

```
userdbelements_id   userdbelements_field_name   userdbelements_field_value  userdb_id
647 heat        1
648 displayorder    1 - Sponsored   1
645 condofees       1
```

userdb

```
userdb_id   userdb_user_name    userdb_emailaddress userdb_user_first_name  userdb_user_last_name
10  harbourlights   info@harbourlightscondosminium.ca   Harbourlights   1237 Northshore Blvd, Burlington
11  harbourview info@harbourviewcondominium.ca  Harbourview 415 Locust Street, Burlington
12  thebalmoral info@thebalmoralcondominium.ca  The Balmoral    2075 & 2085 Amherst Heights Drive, Burlington
```

Comment: Can you post the structure of your tables? I am having difficulty understanding your order by clause.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. userdb contains the users, and userdbelements contains information about them. The fields in userdbelements are userdbelements_id, userdbelements_field_name, userdbelements_field_value, userdb_id (mapped to userdb_id in the userdb table).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an invalid ORDER BY.

```
ORDER BY (t1.userdbelements_field_name = 'displayorder' AND t1.userdbelements_field_value)
```

It must reference a table column or returned aliased column.

I really cannot follow how this query would even be possible as you already have limited 
**t1.userdbelements_field_name** = *newproject* and then you wish to order by the case of it being equal to *displayorder*.

Could you please modify your question to state exactly what it is that you are trying to accomplish in your order by clause?

Comment: actually is limited to t1.userdbelement_field_name = newproject AND t1.userdbelements_field_value = no. And then same with the displayorder, I don't want to sort on displayorder, I want to sort on the value associated with displayorder.

Comment: @Les, could you please provide us with a very small sample of both tables, perhaps 2-3 results each.  It would help a ton.

Comment: Sorry for disappearing, here is some sample data

userdbelements
userdbelements_id userdbelements_field_name userdbelements_field_value userdb_id
647 heat   1
648 displayorder 1 - Sponsored 1
645 condofees   1

userdb
userdb_id userdb_user_name userdb_emailaddress userdb_user_first_name userdb_user_last_name
10 harbourlights info@harbourlightscondosminium.ca Harbourlights 1237 Northshore Blvd, Burlington
11 harbourview info@harbourviewcondominium.ca Harbourview 415 Locust Street, Burlington
12 thebalmoral info@thebalmoralcondominium.ca The Balmoral 2075 & 2085 Amherst Heights Drive, Burlington

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you'd have to join to `default_en_userdbelements` solely for the `displayorder` value. However, I suspect there's something wrong with your query and that it probably returns duplicate values for `userdb_id`.

Perhaps you should say what you're trying to actually do, not explain the way you're trying to do it.

```
  SELECT t1.userdb_id
    FROM default_en_userdbelements AS t1
    JOIN default_en_userdb         AS t2 ON t1.userdb_id = t2.userdb_id

    JOIN default_en_userdbelements AS o  ON (o.userdb_id,  o.userdbelements_field_name)
                                          = (t1.userdb_id, 'displayorder')

   WHERE t1.userdbelements_field_name   = 'newproject'
     AND t1.userdbelements_field_value  = 'no'
     AND t2.userdb_user_first_name     != 'Default'

ORDER BY o.userdbelements_field_value,
         t2.userdb_user_first_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
ORDER BY 
  (CASE WHEN t1.userdbelements_field_name = 'displayorder' 
  THEN t1.userdbelements_field_value 
  ELSE $some_large_number 
  END),
 t2.userdb_user_first_name;
```

It sorts using the value of `t1.userdbelements_field_value` when `t1.userdbelements_field_name = 'displayorder'`, but you have to supply some other value of the same type to apply for the `ELSE`.